# How much memory is given each program when compiled/how is more memory allocated to a program?

Tags: memory, memory-management, stack

From my understanding, when a program compiles, the OS doesn't know how much memory the program will use, so does it just give it an arbitrary amount of memory, say, 200 MB? But if it does, won't really small programs be using too much unnecessary space?

If this is the case, then what happens if a program needs more than 200MB of memory? How does it allocate more space for a program? I'm looking at this image

[image: Image of memory layout]

So if a program runs out of memory, it must expand up, but won't there be another program above this one?